# Django: formsModelMultipleChoiceField data not populating

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I am making 2 very basic account types in my Django project: Instructor and Student. I want a list of the emails of Instructors who have signed up so Students can select their Instructor's email from the list when creating an account, thus linking the two accounts.

forms.py

```
class StudentSignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    instructor_id = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Instructor.objects.all())

    class Meta(UserCreationForm):
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('username', 'inGameName', 'instructor_id')
        help_texts = {
            'username': 'Required',
            'inGameName': 'Required; A name by which you can be identified',
            'instructor_id': 'Optional; Provided by your professor',
        }

    @transaction.atomic
    def save(self):
        user = super().save(commit=False)
        user.is_student = True
        user.save()
        student = Student.objects.create(user=user)
        student.instructor_id = (self.cleaned_data.get('instructor_id'))
        return user


class InstructorSignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(label='Your Email', help_text='Required')

    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('username',  'inGameName', 'email')
        help_texts = {
            'username': 'Required',
            'inGameName': 'Required; A name by which you can be identified',
        }

    @transaction.atomic
    def save(self):
        user = super().save(commit=False)
        user.is_instructor = True
        user.email = self.cleaned_data["email"]
        user.save()
        return user
```

models.py

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    is_student = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_instructor = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=40, primary_key=True, default='')
    inGameName = models.CharField("In-Game Name", max_length=40, default='')

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'


class Instructor(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, default ='USER',on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, unique=True, default='Email@Email.com')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email


class Student(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, default='USER', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    instructor_id = models.ForeignKey(Instructor, to_field='email', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='Email@Email.com')
```

/views/students.py

```
class StudentSignUpView(CreateView):
    model = CustomUser
    form_class = StudentSignUpForm
    template_name = 'student_signup.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('login')

    form = forms.StudentSignUpForm()
    form.fields["instructor_id"].queryset = Instructor.objects.all()
```

/template/student_signup.html

```
 <form method="post" autocomplete="off">
            <div class="signup">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ form.as_p }}
                <button type="submit">Create Account</button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

I expect the list of instructors emails to show up in the ModelMultipleChoiceField however it is empty. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

I can see several issues here.

**Issue #1**

This line in StudentSignUpForm class states that 1 student can have multiple instructors:

```
instructor_id = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(...
```

on the other hand this line in Student class states that 1 student can have only 1 instructor:

```
instructor_id = models.ForeignKey
```

You should either have forms.ModelChoiceField in your form, or models.ManyToManyField in your model.

**Issue #2**

forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField will show emails as choices, but will still by default use pk field as a choice value. To fix this you should either pass a to_field_name='email' argument when defining your instructor_id field (thus changing the default behavior of a ModelChoiceField) or remove to_field='email' argument when defining the instructor_id field in your Student model (making the default behavior relevant for your model). I would personally prefer the latter. Email isn't really a gook foreign key - it can change and you'll have to update both Instructor and Student tables to keep the link.